# how to select with order by alphabetical

Tags: oracle, plsql

I have something like this :

```
Select id , name from table1 (how to orderby alphabetical from the name(column))
```

the result from select should be : 
1.Alex
2.Bob
3.Charlie

Comment: reading http://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/statements_10002.htm (search for "order by") or similar, could have helped.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use this:-

```
Select id , name from table1 ORDER BY NAME
```

By default, the order is ascending. If you want to get the names in the descending order use:-

`ORDER BY NAME DESC`

Comment: Just need to add a ; at the end of the statement. So the statement will be SELECT id, name from table1 ORDER BY NAME;